# Program that writes numbers until I write a string to stop it

Tags: c#

I am required to write a program that prints out numbers until I write in the console window a simple string "stop". The numbers are supposed to go on infinitely until the condition is met.

I tried:

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ConsoleApp3

{

    internal class Program

    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000;)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                string a = Console.ReadLine();
                if (a == "stop")
                {
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But, there is a delay waiting for my input every time, it's not constant.

Comment: Has your coursework covered threads?  Does it have to be the full `string` `"stop"` or can it just be [a single key](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey) like `Esc`?

Comment: what's wrong with `while` loop? 1000000000 is not infinity

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "delay?" Does the logic work for the "stop?"

Comment: @mzimmers I believe they mean that between each number printed `ReadLine()` waits for console input whereas they want it to keep printing numbers whether anything has been input or not.

Comment: @Lance: thanks -- I think you're right. If the OP confirms this, I can edit the question.

Comment: If you don't read at all, then the output will continue until you press `[Ctrl+C]`... does that count?

Answer (score 4):

You are asking for a non blocking console read. THats not simple.

One way is to peek to see if a key is available to read

```
int number = 0;
while (true)
{
   Console.WriteLine(number);
   number++;
   if (Console.KeyAvailable)
   {
       var s = Console.ReadLine();
       if (s == "stop")
          break;
   }
}
```

Comment: I know it's not simple but seriously my professor didn't think this through, we're learning for, while, if methods. He wants me to do this specific one and I wasn't able to find help anywhere. But thank you for the help, it's exactly what I needed.